# What would be good way to get updates made to SQL Server in Real time?

Tags: python, sql-server, postgresql, apache-kafka

I'm trying to find a way to copy data out of SQL Server 2014 and 2017 every time a table has an insert or update performed to it. I'm trying to do it in real time to insert these values into another table in PostgreSQL. Few options that I've explored are batch processing using tools such as:

- Talend ETL tool
- Foreign data wrappers in PostgreSQL that uses cron job to trigger
  procedures that does hourly inserts and updates to PostgreSQL table
  using data from SQL Server table.

I'm not sure how to get events from SQL server in real time that I can link with something like Kafka or even something like Python microservices or if there is a better way.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/688ec345-813e-4028-a7b1-1839e4af9d7b/call-a-dll-or-exe-file-from-sql-trigger?forum=sqlnetfx

Using a cron job that runs every minute and polls is also not a terrible idea. Obviously save changes to another tale inside the trigger.

Comment: What about insert/update triggers on the sql server and a linked server to postgresql?

Comment: @MaxSzczurek It sounds like a good idea. Is there any caveats to using triggers on SQL server where there are few 100 inserts done in an hour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use triggers

> Create SQL Server & Postgresql tables:

```
-- SQL Server
create table test (id int identity(1,1) not null primary key, name varchar(25), description varchar(1000))
go

-- Postgresql:
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
    id integer,
    name character varying(25) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description character varying(1000) COLLATE pg_catalog."default"
)
```

> Create a linked server in SQL Server to your Postgresql server.
>
> Then create triggers on your SQL Server table:

```
create trigger iu_trigger_name on test
after insert, update
as 
begin
    UPDATE [SQLAuth_PG].[DefaultDB].[public].[test]
    SET name = t.name, description = t.description
    FROM [SQLAuth_PG].[DefaultDB].[public].[test] p
    INNER JOIN inserted t ON p.id = t.id

    INSERT INTO [SQLAuth_PG].[DefaultDB].[public].[test]
           ([id]
           ,[name]
           ,[description])
    SELECT t.id, t.name, t.description
    FROM inserted t
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM [SQLAuth_PG].[DefaultDB].[public].[test] 
        WHERE id = t.id
    )
end
go

create trigger d_trigger_name on test
after delete 
as
begin
    delete p
    FROM [SQLAuth_PG].[DefaultDB].[public].[test] p
    inner join deleted d on p.id = d.id
end
go
```

> Test:

```
insert into test (name, description) select 'Name1', 'Name 1 description'
go

select * from [SQLAuth_PG].[DefaultDB].[public].[test]

--output
--id    name    description
--1 Name1   Name 1 description

update test set description = 'Updated description!' where name = 'Name1'
go

select * from [SQLAuth_PG].[DefaultDB].[public].[test]

-- output
--id    name    description
--1 Name1   Updated description!

delete from test
go

select * from [SQLAuth_PG].[DefaultDB].[public].[test]
go

-- postgresql table is empty
```

The trigger in this example handles batch inserts and updates. That's the only real pitfall with triggers - assuming there's only one record in the "inserted" table. After a bulk insert or update, the inserted table is populated with all the new/modified records.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go the Kafka route, there are several options for getting data out of SQL Server into Kafka:

- For log based CDC:

  - [Debezium](https://www.confluent.io/connector/debezium-sql-server-cdc-connector/)
  - [kafka-connect-cdc-microsoft-sql](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-cdc-microsoft-sql/)
  - Plus Attunity, Goldengate, et al
- For query based CDC:

  - [kafka-connect-jdbc](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-jdbc/) Source

Once the data's in Kafka you can stream it to Postgres (or any other database) using the [kafka-connect-jdbc](https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-jdbc/) Sink.